# ScalaJS plugin 0.6.23: "value %%% is not a member of String"

Tags: sbt, scala.js

After migrating to ScalaJS `0.6.23` from `0.6.21`:

(`addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.23")`)

My `sbt`-build throws the following exception:

```
...
[error] /Users/mpa/dev/Github/pme123/scala-adapters/project/Settings.scala:88:20: value %%% is not a member of String
[error]     "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.9.6"
[error]                    ^
[error] /Users/mpa/dev/Github/pme123/scala-adapters/project/Settings.scala:90:27: value %%% is not a member of String
[error]     , "com.typesafe.play" %%% "play-json" % "2.6.1"
...
```

This is the value from the `Settings.scala`:

```
  lazy val clientDependencies: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Def.settings(libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.9.6"
    , "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.6"
    , ...
  ))
```

And this is how it is used in `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val client = (project in file("client"))
  .settings(sharedSettings(Some("client")))
  .settings(clientSettings)
  .settings(clientDependencies)
  .settings(jsSettings)
  .enablePlugins(ScalaJSWeb)
  .dependsOn(sharedJs)
```

This is the project: https://github.com/pme123/scala-adapters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [release notes of Scala.js 0.6.23](https://www.scala-js.org/news/2018/05/22/announcing-scalajs-0.6.23/) say that

> Usages of `%%%` in `.scala` files of an sbt build (under `project/`) need a new import:
>
> ```scala
> import org.portablescala.sbtplatformdeps.PlatformDepsPlugin.autoImport._
> ```
>
> For `.sbt` files, this import is automatically added, so nothing changes.

So you need to add

```scala
import org.portablescala.sbtplatformdeps.PlatformDepsPlugin.autoImport._
```

in your `Settings.scala` file.